# Use if False and print without stopping Loop

Tags: python, if-statement, output

I have defined a "value" and I have an IF statement such as:

```
value = any ("1" in valueMaj for valueMaj in list)
if value == False:
```

Can I make it so my print statement prints out ALL that are not true, not just one. Example:

INPUT

```
print("FILE NOT MATCH:", file)
```

OUTPUT

```
FILE NOT MATCH: filenumber1.txt
```

But, I would like it to print all that do not match rather than stopping the loop.

Comment: Don't use `value == False`. Use `not value` to test for false values.

Comment: Don't use `list` as a name for a variable, that masks the built-in type.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `any()` if you need all values that do not match. Create a list instead using a list comprehension with a filter:

```
not_matching = [valueMaj for valueMaj in some_list if '1' not in valueMaj]
if not_matching:
    print('The following files do not match:', ', '.join(not_matching))
```

or use a loop to print out individual files.

`any()` will short-circuit and stop iterating; it is only useful for efficient testing of a condition against a sequence, not for filtering that sequence.

Comment: For some reason it prints out all of the files, there is decimal so I did try "1." and "1" after the if. Any suggestions? By the way thank you!

Comment: @Girls.Gone.Wired: sorry, without sample input data and expected output, that's impossible to answer.

Comment: I believe the problem is the the "value" is reading in as a String. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: `value` in your question is always going to be a `bool`, either `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import shutil
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import glob
import re
import fileinput

root_dir = os.getcwd()
uop_dir = root_dir + "\\UoP"

  # .h files
  print ("Searching for .h files: " + uop_dir)
  for root, subfolders, files in os.walk(uop_dir):
   if root.endswith("WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE"):
   if myfile.endswith(".h"):
      print (root + "/" + myfile)
      for file in myfiles:
      for line in open(file):
         line = line.rstrip()
         if re.search('VERSION\s+("\d+\.\d+")$', line):
            version = re.findall("\d+\.\d+" , line)
            # version.append(file)
            if re.search('VERSION\s+("\d+\.\d+")$', line):

                    valueMaj = re.findall('\d+\.', line)
                    ###print(valueMaj)
                    #FINDS MINOR NUMBER
                    if re.search('VERSION\s+("\d+\.\d+")$', line):
                            valueMin = re.findall('\.\d+' , line)
                         ###print(valueMin)
                            value = [valueMaj for valueMaj in file if ('1.7') not in valueMaj]

                            if value:
                                    ###print("FILE NOT MATCH:", file, "\nROOT: " root, "\nVERSION: ", *version)
                                    print("FILE NOT MATCH:", file , "\nVERSION: ", version, "\nMAJOR_NUMBER:", (valueMaj),
                                           "\nMINOR_NUMBER: ", ''.join(valueMin))
```